# Linked Lists - Remove Element at an Index

Tags: java, linked-list

I am working on a Linked Lists assignment for my OOP class, and have run into some trouble with a remove method. Our professor has asked us to write a method:

```
public Object removeElement(int index)
```

This takes an index, which is the location of the element that needs removed. It must return the data the deleted node contained as well. However, I am having trouble with getting the method to return the object it is removing. For some reason I keep getting the error that the method must return a result of type object. I have it returning an object, and I've gone through trial and error in various spots with no success.
Here is my code:

```
 public Object removeElement(int index)
   {
   ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
   Object object;
   //If the supplied index is less than zero, throw an exception.
   if(index < 0)
   {
       IndexOutOfBoundsException ex = new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
       throw ex;
   }

   else
   {
       for(int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
       {
           if(!iterator.hasNext())
           {
               IndexOutOfBoundsException ex = new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
               throw ex;
           }
           else
           {
               if(i == index)
               {
                   object = iterator.next();
                   iterator.remove();
                   return object;
               }
               else
               {
                   iterator.next();

               }
           }
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: Does the error give a line number? What is the full error message?

Comment: The error isn't at compilation, it is in the method before I even compile.

Comment: @DanielPikul: That effectively *is* a compilation error. It's just your IDE basically compiling as you type.

Comment: I learn more in 30 minutes on here than I do in 13 weeks of class. :) I never knew exactly what to call that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it returning an object *if* `i == index`. But the compiler doesn't know that the loop will actually always end at that point. It's looking at the bottom of the loop and thinking "What do we want to return if we get here?"

I would actually restructure your code to:

```
if (index < 0)
{
    // No need for a separate variable
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}

// No need for an else block
ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
Object current = null;
for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
{
    // Note: assuming you expose the size(), you could check this up front...
    if(!iterator.hasNext())
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    current = iterator.next();
}
iterator.remove();
return current;
```

Now you *always* call `remove` and return when you've called `next()` the given number of times, because that's when the loop will end other than via an exception.

Comment: How can I fix that then? I have the method throwing an exception if it doesn't reach it, I was hoping that would take care of it.

Comment: Okay, I'm comparing them real quick.

Comment: Great! Thank you!!! I actually kept my code and just set the Object to null originally and wrote a return line outside of the loops. Your code was definitely much simpler and helped me think about it though.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly do not use iterator from java LinkedList it is [Doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) , I think professor wants to see how you implement remove functionality for [LikedList](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) data structure.

Secondly make loop and condition where `i+1 == index` in this place, save current element for return like `Node returnElement = curent.next;` and make delete manipulation `curent.next  = curent.next.next;`

Answer (score 0):

Pls post listIterator() method implementation and the error message that you are getting.
Note:> You have to manage the size of the list using an class variable such as an integer. So you dont have check !iterator.hasNext(), instead compare index with current size.

Comment: LinkedLists do not have a stored size index, that is ArrayLists. I have to use hasNext();

Comment: LinkedLists don't have a size?  What is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#size()) then?

Comment: Something we are not allowed to use in this class. We are using a custom LinkedList subset written by our professor. I should have clarified that.

Comment: @DanielPikul - No worries... was just wondering if I had gone insane for a moment ;-)

Comment: Yes, but you have used Index to remove the element. It should not be. remove (Element ) method should only be there. Please refer java.util.LinkedList